# Plugins not showing in Multisite dashboard

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have been trying to upload more plugins and even though the files are all located in content/plugins directory, nothing is showing up in the dashboard.

Even the default plugins are not showing. Does anyone know why this may be?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Plugins for network sites, via the Network Admin?

Also, MU (must-use) or network-activated Plugins won't show in the site dashboard, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

You have likely Network Activated all of your plugins. If there are options for the plugins, these will appear in the Child site admin sidebar navigation. Plugins that have not been Network Activated will appear in the Child site admin under Plugins, with the option to activate them on a site-by-site basis.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen on a multisite before and what I ended up doing was programmatically deactivating/reactivating the plugin again using [activate_plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/activate_plugin) and [deactivate_plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/deactivate_plugins). And it seemed to show up in my case. The plugin that wasn't showing up in my case was Post Type Switcher, a Network Plugin.

```
//deactivate/reactivate the plugin on theme switch
function post_type_switcher_activator(){

    //reference the plugin's main php file
    deactivate_plugins( array( 'post-type-switcher/post-type-switcher.php' ) );
    activate_plugin( 'post-type-switcher/post-type-switcher.php', NULL , false);
}
add_action('switch_theme', 'post_type_switcher_activator');
```

Not sure if those other two args to activate plugin are needed.  I did the activating/deactivating based on theme switching (so that it wouldn't happen *every* time). So to see if this works, just switch out to another theme and switch back, and then see if the plugin shows up in your list.  Post Type Switcher did for me.